# Unable to locate elements using text in xpath

Tags: xpath

I'm trying to locate an element by using text in xpath like this `//*[contains(text(),'Provider is 3243 miles away')]` but it's unable to find that. After inspecting and expanding the element I see the text as follows
[image]

If I collapse the element then it shows like this

```
<span class="text-muted" data-nw-node="span" data-nw-file="WorkOrderCondition">Provider is 3243 miles away /4492 minutes</span>
```

Can anyone help me, please?

Comment: the text in your xpath and the html element are not matching. Can you please share the html of the span element with the text that you want to access.

Comment: I don't know what tool you're using to display the XML, and I don't know why it's splitting up the text and putting parts of it in quotes, but it suggests to me that the text you are looking for is not contiguous text within a single text node.

Comment: @supputuri I've updated my question

Comment: Can you please provide the html of the ancestor div. So that we can validate the xpath correctly.

Comment: `//span[contains(text(),'Provider is 3207 miles away')]` is working as expected. But the code that you share and the screenshot span not matching (in screenshot the text is present in multiple lines but code is showing all the text in single line)

Comment: @supputuri I'm am unable to match and it's actually a react component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending a couple of hours I found a solution. For my case, every word was showing with a new line and I resolved it by this way

Either: `//*[contains(., 'Provider is 3243 miles away')][normalize-space(text())]`

Or: `(//*[contains(., 'Provider is 3243 miles away')])[last()]`